# Ajax not being loaded to the view rails 3 will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, will-paginate

Im trying to implement an Ajax call with the will_paginate gem, I found this guide http://ramblinglabs.com/blog/2011/11/rails-3-1-will_paginate-and-ajax which seemed like a simple solution, though it includes coffeescript which i am not familiar with

My code is as follows

My View

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div id="userRecipes">
   <%= render partial: 'userrecipes' %>
 </div>
</div><!--/row-->
```

My partial (userrecipes)

```
 <% @recipes.each do |r| %>
  <div class="span3">
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <%= image_tag r.avatar.url(:myrecipes) %>
   </div>
   <h4><%= link_to r.dish_name, r %></h4>
   <hr>
    <p><%= truncate r.description, :length => 90 %></p>
    <p><%= link_to "Edit Recipe", edit_recipe_path(r.id) %></p>
    <p><%= link_to "Delete Recipe", recipe_path(r.id), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %></p>
    <p><%= link_to "Add to favorites",  {:controller => 'favourites', :action => 'create', :recipe_id => r.id}, {:method => :post } %></p>
   </div><!--/span3-->
   <% end %>
   <%= will_paginate @recipes %>
```

userrecipes.js.erb file

```
$('#userRecipes').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'userrecipes') %>');
$.setAjaxPagination();
```

Coffeescript

```
$ ->
$.setAjaxPagination = ->
$('.pagination a').click (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  loading = $ '<div id="loading" style="display: none;"><span><img src="/assets/loading.gif" alt="cargando..."/></span></div>'
  $('.other_images').prepend loading
  loading.fadeIn()
  $.ajax type: 'GET', url: $(@).attr('href'), dataType: 'script', success: (-> loading.fadeOut -> loading.remove())
  false

  $.setAjaxPagination()
```

When i click on the next anchor tag to show the next set of results the page stays as it is and no new content appears

When using the console to see if there are any errors i can see any, the output is

```
GET http://localhost:3000/my_recipes?page=2&_=1355055997639
```

Am i missing something here?

Also Whilst inspecting the response in the console it is also showing that the new recipes to be loaded are being loaded but nothing is happening in the view

Any pointers appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a `console.log("js response received")` line to your userrecipes.js.erb file and after clicking on pagination check the browser console(firebug etc.) to see if this is printed out...

Comment: ok so i have done that and i cannot see it in my response? What is going on?

Comment: in your console where you see the `GET` request.. check it will show you the controller and action where the request has gone ..Does it shows the format as #html or #js

Comment: What is the filename of your "main" view template? Is it `index.html.erb`? If so, you probably need to name the js template as `index.js.erb` instead of `userrecipes.js.erb` (or render `userrecipes.js.erb` in the controller).

Comment: the filename is my_recipes.html.erb

Comment: @dimuch, thankyou, it was my naming conventions..silly mistake, just to clarify if i want to use .js.erb files then it has to match the name of the view template? do you want to put it as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: You can use any name for the view template. But if it differs from the controller method, make sure you have let Rails know where to find the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links created by will_paginate are html links...

use following code

```
 $('.pagination a').attr('data-remote', 'true');
```

to add data-remote true property to them so they make an `js` request to the server...

Comment: sorry for basic question but where do i put this, in the js.erb file? or in the coffeescript?

Comment: call this js code from your view or userrecipe partial in document ready function of it..

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in js.erb file.

```
$('.pagination a').attr('data-remote', 'true');
```

this should work.